# Stop music player on device home button android

Tags: android, event-handling, android-mediaplayer, android-homebutton

I have an android application in which am try to play a background sound for an particular activity(sound will play on single activity not for an whole application).
Am using this code to start the MediaPlayer

```
MediaPlayer backMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theme_loop);
backMP.setLooping(true);
backMP.start();
```

It is working fine but I just want to stop the music on home button press for this I have try
`backMP.release()`, `backMp.stop()` in `onPause()` method nothing is work for me.

Comment: Can you post the code to your activity? Both of the proposed answers are valid.

Answer (score 0):

use `backMP.stop` in both onDestroy,onStop,and onPause it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        Log.d("Test", "Home button pressed!");
        backMP.stop(); 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or you can use like that start playing in onResume()

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
                   backMP.start(); 
                    }
```

and stop in onpouse() like that

```
  @Override
      protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
        backMP.stop(); 
     }
```

Comment: I don't think that is going to work, Android doesn't allow you to capture the Home key event. Something about malicious content...

Comment: It would be better to use OnPause. And OnResume to start playing again when the application is re-opened.

Comment: if i'll comment this then it will automatically stop after finish the sound. It is just for repeat the sound.